# Releasing a code in visual studio 2010 C#

Tags: c#

I wrote a program in C# with visual studio 2010 an now need to ensure that my program will work on any system with XP or seven or vista windows version.
I used from .net & directX in my project.
How can i compact it with an installer on start up?

Comment: What do you mean by "compact it with an installer on startup?"

Comment: (please don't do the "Hi dears." thing)

Answer (score 5):

Install Virtual PC or VMWare and install the OS's you need to test against.

Answer (score 4):

So, if I'm right with what I think you're asking...

You essentially want to make sure that your application will run on any system XP or greater, especially given that you have reference dependencies from the .net framework and DirectX.

If you create an installer project within Visual Studio, you can then configure it to check for prerequisites.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7eh4aaa5(v=vs.80).aspx

That's probably a good place to start. Most installer builders will allow you to specify prerequisites for your application and check for them during install.

[edit] ... and then do what Mitch suggested and test it to death on a variety of virtual OS's.